# reading data from csv file to store in an int list c# windows form

Tags: c#, winforms, list, csv

i am curently trying to create a windows form application for college to calculate and display postage costs which are read from a csv file.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.IO;

namespace ParcelEXDelivery
{
    public partial class frmParcelCalculator : Form
    {

        int price, insurance;
        string file;
        List<int> UK = new List<int>();
        List<int> RestOfEurope = new List<int>();
        List<int> Worldwide = new List<int>();


        public frmParcelCalculator()
        {
            InitializeComponent();


        }

        private void destination()
        {

            if (rbUK.Checked)
            {

                file = "..\\Debug\\PostageCosts.csv";
                var reader = new StreamReader(file);
                while (!reader.EndOfStream)
                {
                    var line = reader.ReadLine();
                    var values = line.Split(',');

                    UK.Add(int.Parse(values[0]));

                }
                reader.Close();
                display();
            }
        }

        public void display()
        {
            label2.Text = UK[price].ToString();

        }
```

I know this while be quite simple, but i'm not great at coding. The program is bringing up an error for

```
UK.Add(int.Parse(values[0]));
```

What can I do to fix this? Or have I got this set out all wrong? I'm trying to display in a label just to see if the correct postage cost is output

```
16.5    27.3    41.6    52.4    66.2    0.6 per kg  UK
21.5    31.3    45.1    58.5    71.5    0.7 per kg  Rest of Europe
27.4    37.2    50.3    62.4    76.3    0.75 per kg Worldwide
```

That is the csv file

```
private void destination()
        {

            if (rbUK.Checked)
            {
                var file = "..\\Debug\\Questions.csv";
                if (File.Exists(file))
                {
                    var f = File.OpenRead(file);
                    var reader = new StreamReader(f);

                    while (!reader.EndOfStream)
                    {
                        var row = reader.ReadLine();
                        if (row != null)
                        {
                            var values = row.Split(',');

                            foreach (var item in values)
                            {

                                if (decimal.TryParse(values[0], out Value))
                                {
                                    UK.Add(Value);
                                }
                                else
                                {

                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

That is the edited method above and below is the code when I try to output the values to a label and it says you cannot convert from decimal to int.

```
        public void display()
        {
            label2.Text = UK[Value].ToString();

        }
```

Comment: In the file, are there spaces or tabs between elements?

Comment: You're splitting the strings by "," but there are no commas in the lines

Comment: Since this is for college I take it using something like [FileHelpers](https://github.com/MarcosMeli/FileHelpers) is out?

Comment: bringing up _what_ error?

Comment: @VolkanPaksoy, that's why I asked what the separator was.

Comment: @LegionMammal978: Sure. It was in response to his question "Or have I got this set out all wrong?"

Comment: the .csv file is an excel file so values only separated by columns @LegionMammal978

Comment: An unhandled exception of type 'System.FormatException' occurred in mscorlib.dll

Additional information: Input string was not in a correct format. @TimSchmelter

Answer (score 0):

Yes you have set it up quite wrongly. The main problem are your values. You have decimal numbers to parse, not integers. So your lists should reflect this basic condition. Create `List<decimal>` not `List<int>`

```
List<decimal> UK = new List<decimal>();
List<decimal> RestOfEurope = new List<decimal>();
List<decimal> Worldwide = new List<decimal>();
```

Then, the parsing part is not too much wrong. If your file contains only decimal numbers formatted according to your culture (decimal point is a point or a comma?) you could easily read them back using `decimal.Parse` but as explained in other answers, it is always better to use a defensive approach and call decimal.TryParse to be free from unexpected (and easy avoidable) exceptions.

```
  decimal curValue;
  if(decimal.TryParse(values[0], out curValue))
     UK.Add(curValue);
  //else
  //   ... if you want some kind of error reporting here ...
```

**EDIT**

There is something to be fixed also in the way in which you read your file.
It seems that you have three lines, the values in the first line should go in the first list (UK) the values on the second line should go in the second list (RestOfEurope) and the third line in Worldwide list. I suggest to read all the lines together and then assign the values at the appropriate lists

```
private void destination()
{

    if (rbUK.Checked)
    {
        // Read all the lines in a single call, 
        string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines(@".\Debug\PostageCosts.csv");

        // I expect to have three lines but better to check before acting on the array

        if(lines.Length > 0)
        {
            // Split the line for UK and use only the first 6 values
            // for the list (the last strings 'per kg  UK' should not be added)
            // Again, at least 6 decimal values are expected not less...
            var values = lines[0].Split(',');
            if(values.Length >= 6)
                for(int x = 0; x < 6; x++)
                    UK.Add(decimal.Parse(values[x]));
        }
        if(lines.Length > 1)
        {
            var values = lines[1].Split(',');
            if(values.Length >= 6)
                for(int x = 0; x < 6; x++)
                    RestOfEurop.Add(decimal.Parse(values[x]));
        }
        if(lines.Length > 2)
        {
            var values = lines[2].Split(',');
            if(values.Length >= 6)
                for(int x = 0; x < 6; x++)
                    WorlWide.Add(decimal.Parse(values[x]));
        }
        // Test what list to display passing the index 0,1,2
        int listToShow = 0;
        display(listToShow);
    }
}
public void display(int listToShow)
{
    List<decimal> showList = (listToShow == 0 ? UK : 
                              listToShow == 1 ? RestOfEurope : 
                                                WorlWide);
    label2.Text = string.Join("-",  showList.ToArray());
}
```

Comment: i have tried this and everything is all okay except for when I want to output values. "label2.Text = UK[curValue];"  Should it be .ToString() at the end?

Comment: Yes, add it and you should see your decimal value converted to a string using the formatting convetions of your culture

Comment: i tried that but it says you cannot convert from decimal to int?

Comment: Could you show what are you trying to do? (the line that raises the error)